# Grouping for Long List Selector cannot convert at the last part

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, grouping, longlistselector

I have the following classes:

```
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private readonly IGrouping<TKey, TElement> _group;
    public Grouping(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> group)
    {
        this._group = group;
    }
    public TKey Key { get { return _group.Key; } }
    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _group.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _group.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Sections
{
    public IEnumerable<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code using it (organisationRepository returns an IEnumerable):

```
        organisationRepository = new OrganisationRepository();
        var tempOrganisations = await organisationRepository.GetAll();
        var groupedOrganisations = from currentOrg in tempOrganisations
                                   group currentOrg by currentOrg.name into grouped
                                   select new Grouping<string, Organisation>(grouped);

        sections.Organisations = groupedOrganisations; 
        Organisations = null;
```

sections.Organisations is an `IEnumerable<Organisation>` and so i'm getting the following error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<*.ViewModel.Grouping<string,*.Models.*.Models.Entities.Organisation>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<*.Models.*.Models.Entities.Organisation>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\*\*\ViewModel\DashboardViewModel.cs    65  38  *
```

Any ideas how I am to convert the grouping into an IEnumerable

sources:

http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/NoelRice/noel-rice/2011/08/12/Categorized_Lists_with_Windows_Phone_7_LongListSelector

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-longlistselector-control

Better sources: (I'll give these a try now that I have found)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

big thanks to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlfNsw_JM6U

**EDIT://**

I'm now home and have tried lots of various things, the problem still exists with converting to an IEnumerable

```
+       $exception  {System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[*.ViewModel.AlphaKeyGroup`1[*.Models.*.Models.Entities.Organisation]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[*.Models.*.Models.Entities.Organisation]'.
   at *.ViewModel.DashboardViewModel.<LoadOrganisationSection>d__2.MoveNext()}  System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}
```

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
var tempOrganisations = await organisationRepository.GetAll();
            List<AlphaKeyGroup<Organisation>> groupedOrganisations = AlphaKeyGroup<Organisation>.CreateGroups(tempOrganisations,
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                (Organisation o) => { return o.name; }, true);


            sections.Organisations = (IEnumerable<Organisation>)groupedOrganisations;
```

using Microsoft's own AlphaKeyGroup class

Comment: There is something wrong in what you are trying to achieve. The result of that groupedOrganisations query will be a List of Grouping<string,Organization>, you can't convert this into IEnumerable<Organizations>, can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am preparing an IEnumerable list for that Long list selector control which requires some grouping key thingy ma bobby. This is what I was following: http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/NoelRice/noel-rice/2011/08/12/Categorized_Lists_with_Windows_Phone_7_LongListSelector ... Should the Grouping<string, Organization> be something like <string, IEnumerable<organization> I must admit, I'm not sure I understand the grouping function so I just guess worked the new grouping

Comment: The grouping should be based on the "name" property of my Organisation

Comment: It may be helpful to state that i'm also trying to do MVVM so doing code behind for this item and just assigning the value to it isn't an option

Comment: I just converted my viewmodel version of the data to List<AlphaKeyGroup<Organisation>> and it solved the issue.. YEHAAA